# CardView background color states not being respected

Tags: android, android-cardview

In brief:

How can we define color states of CardView's cardBackgroundColor property (in a ListView layout, in this case)?

(I am using RC1 of Android L developer preview, on a phone with 4.4 installed, and "com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1" in build.gradle)

Longer:

In CardView layout, we set the corner radius and background color of the CardView via cardCornerRadius and cardBackgroundColor.

However, the background color doesn't repect selected states, i.e. if the list item is pressed, for example.

If, in the inner view of the CardView, you set a background colour, and associated states, which are respected, however, it will display over the corners you defined in the CardView.

So, how can we ensure the states in CardView's cardBackgroundColor are respected?

Here's the color used for the cardBackgroundColor, colour_with_states.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <!-- Only this below is seen in the cardview dispaly -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
</selector>
```

And the layout that uses the CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colour_with_states"
    >

<!-- If we set a background color below, it will overwrite our radius defined above -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:text="Lorem ipsum"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:paddingStart="8dip"
    android:paddingEnd="8dip"
    />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Does using the same background color in a regular `FrameLayout` respect the selected states? I take it you are calling `setOnClickListener` on your `CardView`?

Comment: I think the answer is in your question: `If, in the inner view of the CardView, you set a background colour, and associated states, which are respected, however, it will display over the corners you defined in the CardView.` . The parent ViewGroup (card) is routing focus and events to child view. Also, `ListView` has its own `selector` for highlighting selected items.

Comment: @S.D. "Routing" is not how it works.  You should test android:duplicateParentState.  By this means both the parent AND any interested children can implicitly respond with XML selectors to events of interest.  CardView breaks this pattern, and cannot 'hear' the parent selection state change, probably because the attribute in question is the special cardview:cardBackgroundColor, not the generic android:background.

Comment: Hope [this][1] may help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518376/override-android-l-cardview-state-pressed-for-older-versions-of-android

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Though this is not ideal, since the edges are not rounded, you can add touch feedback to a `CardView` like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    //Nested View ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adding the `android:foreground` and `android:clickable` attributes to the `CardView`.

Also this has a negative side effect in that the `android:clickable` attribute overrides any clickListener, and therefore those clickListeners don't get triggered.

### Update

I have some examples of CardView implementations

Loop (https://github.com/lawloretienne/Loop) -
https://github.com/lawloretienne/Loop/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/category_card.xml

QuickReturn (https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn) - https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_quick_return.xml

### Update 2

After more research I have come up with a good solution for CardViews on all API versions including pre-Lollipop.

https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/layout-tips-for-pre-and-post-lollipop-bcb2e4cdd6b2#.9h0v1gmaw

Comment: You should be able to achieve the same effect using android:onClick="someMethod" in place of android:clickable="true" above.

Comment: Not applicable solution. Ugly.

Comment: Actually this does work in either Kit Kat or Lollipop. Just tested and confirmed working! Besides that, it's an perfect simple solution.

Comment: to change the colour of the ripple you can add <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_color</item> to your theme.

Comment: This is a good solution.  It does not override the View's OnClickListener as mentioned in answer, at least not as of support library 24+.

Comment: We don't need to add the clickable attribute if we are already handling the onclick

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes, you may want the `CardView` to have visual touch feedback. The `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` solution is perfect for this.

However, you may consider using `drawSelectorOnTop(true)` with your ListView. This will require no change on your `CardView` at all.

Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my way to solve your problem.

First, create a custom class named `CustomCardView` extends `CardView`

Then override the `drawableStateChanged()` method, change the card background color by call `setCardBackgroundColor()` method when card's press status changed.

Last, replace the CardView with this CustomCardView in you layout file.

the only one disadvantage of this solution is cardview can't display ripple press effect on Android 5.0 and above.

here's my code:

```
public class CustomCardView extends CardView {

public CustomCardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    if (isPressed()) {
        this.setCardBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.card_view_pressed));
    } else {
        this.setCardBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.card_view_normal));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

One workaround which I used was to do the UI changes programmatically by overriding the View.OnTouchListener OnTouch() event handler within my custom ViewHolder.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
    {
        mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(STATE_PRESSED_COLOR);
    } 
    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) 
    {
        mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Just add there lines inside card view **

```
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use color state in code and it work perfectly.

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.card_view_selectable))
```

in color > card_view_selectable.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#4fc3f7" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="#fff" />
</selector>
```

Then use isActivated cause background color changed to state_activated or default.

```
cardView.isActivated = true    // or false
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a rectangle shape with the same corner radius as the cardview. And then used the xml drawable as a background for the inner view of the cardview.
The background does not display over cardview corner, though i still get a small padding between the card and its inner view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the definition of carBackgroundColor property, at least in android support library it is:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CardView">
        <!-- Background color for CardView. -->
        <attr name="cardBackgroundColor" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resource>
```

Here it says it takes only color for cardBackgroundValue. I guess this means selector is not respected but falls through to the default value ie. color at the bottom of your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:foreground` instead of `android:background` in your `<CardView/>`.  below are sample code of a CardView .

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

// others view component 

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```